# Как передать метод в rules Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

У меня есть контроллер из которого нужно достать число и проверить в rules, то есть price нужно передать так:

```
return [
            ['price', 'required'],
            ['price', 'number', 'min' => $invest->price],
        ];
```

Контроллер:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {

        if (Yii::$app->request->get('id')) {
            /*$invest = Invest::FindOne(Yii::$app->request->get('id'));*/

            $model = new InvestUser();
            $model->ref = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
            $model->price = Yii::$app->user->identity->mon;
            $model->invest_id = Yii::$app->request->get('id');
            if($model->save()){
                Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('alert', [
                    'body'=>Yii::t('frontend', 'Переведено'),
                    'options'=>['class'=>'alert-success']
                ]);


            }else {
                Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('alert', [
                    'body'=>Yii::t('frontend', 'Ошибка.'),
                    'options'=>['class'=>'alert-success']
                ]);
            }


            return $this->render('start');

        } else {
            return $this->render('index');


        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
            ['price', 'required'],
            ['price', 'number', 'min' => $this->invest->price],
        ];
}


public function getInvest()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Invest::className, ['id'=>'invest_id']);
}
```